# Working with Firebase permissions for making data readonly once created

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am working on an eCommerce web app, I need to make orders on the database readonly once created that is prevent editing orders users generate even by site administrators.

I have this in my rules

```
"orders":{
    "$order": {
      ".read": "$order == auth.uid || auth.isAdmin == true",
        ".write": "$order == auth.uid && (data.child('orders').child($order).hasChildren(['items', 'datePlace', 'shipping', 'totalPriceOfOrder']) !== newData.hasChildren(['items', 'datePlace', 'shipping', 'totalPriceOfOrder'])"
     },
    ".read": "auth.isAdmin == true"
}
```

The purpose of this `($order == auth.uid || auth.isAdmin == true)` in the `".write"` at `$order` is the make sure that only signed in users can write into orders object and at at items with there uid as keys.

The purpose for the `(data.child('orders').child($order).hasChildren(['items', 'datePlace', 'shipping', 'totalPriceOfOrder']) !== newData.hasChildren(['items', 'datePlace', 'shipping', 'totalPriceOfOrder'])` is to ensure that this write is only possible if table does not previously exist.

This is not working and I don't know why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually says that if `auth.uid == $order`, authenticated your can write into database or modify

```
".write": "$order == auth.uid && (data.child('orders').child($order).hasChildren(['items', 'datePlace', 'shipping', 'totalPriceOfOrder']) !== newData.hasChildren(['items', 'datePlace', 'shipping', 'totalPriceOfOrder'])"
```

For read only use

```
".read": "$order == auth.uid || auth.isAdmin == true"
".write": "!data.exists()"
```

The `!data.exists()` will allow you to write once to database and won't allow update or delete. User can read it but not update.

Comment: Your solutions worked but there seems to be another issue, auth.isAdmin is denied permissions on the client but not on simulation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: So I have been able to make this read only with the answer provided below, but with my new rules I noticed that isAdmin is not able to read from the Object, this is the new rule.

 "orders":{
    "$userOrders": {
        ".read": "$userOrders == auth.uid || auth.isAdmin === true",
        ".write": "!data.exists()"
    },
    ".read": "auth.isAdmin === true"
 },